# How to reload a tableview where each cell has a countdown timer that's already started

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstimer, reloaddata

I've created a tableview with custom UITableViewCell subclass that has a countdown timer in each cell.  The user is able to start/stop the timer with a button.  This works fine.

My issue is new cells are supposed to be created and fetched from a server periodically.  I guess I was thinking I can use a NSTimer and keep reloading data to display the new cells but what if I do not want it to affect my countdown timers that have already been started?

Or is there a way my tableview can be updated everytime new data arrives from the server instead of in timed intervals?

Hope that makes sense.  I am not sure what the best method/least expensive way to do this is.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a tableview and each cell having countdown timer and its works perfect.

The issue occur when you add a new row (reload tableview) , if it's the issue mean,

You can do the below steps,

1. create a new mutable array when start a tableview array and load with empty timer.
2. When reload table(add a row/cell) make a loop and update a mutable array with updated timer data. also some data to you make understand like **BOOL isStarted** (do this before reload tableview).
3. cellForRowAtIndexPath  should have check with isstarted or not and you can make your own customize code.

   4.So you need to check with 2 mutable array , one is data source array and another one is your customize array.

(You can try to do this customize array with in your data source array ,that's also possible).

It may help you if i am understand your issue correct.

If this is not make resolve your issue, please edit your question ith sample coding part will make better solution.   :)

Comment: Thanks!  I will check try this out later.